# Equation to show less than sign for multiple points

Tags: equations

I want to show in my article a mathematical equation to express following expression

```
for i=1 to n
Pi < qi
```

How can I write this expression as an equation of proper form in LaTeX ?

Comment: Use `algorithmicx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be interpreted in many ways. I am assuming, that you want the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\} (P_i<q_i)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]